# Want to recieve gps co-ordinates from arduino and send back the location for that co-ordinates back to arduino

Tags: gps, arduino, gsm

i am doing a project which takes gps cordinates from the gps module and send sms of those locations through gsm module for preset numbers . But , i want to upgrade this. I want to send the name of that location through sms  after gathering the gps co-ordinates value . How to do this ? Is there a need of setting up the database to match the co-ordinates ? I am new to these things

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: I dont know much about software part as i am from electronics background. It would be helpful if some one gives sample code and tell how to use it

Answer (score 0):

A service to map coordinates to place names is called a "reverse geocoder".  For example, see this API reference for Android:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

You may need an active Internet connection for this service to work, however.

Comment: could you please give same codes and how to use that ? It would be helpful as i am beginner

Comment: Google is usually very good at finding examples.  I tried "android geocoder example", see:  https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1CATAAB_enUS613US613&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android+geocoder+example+code&spell=1